# $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ for $0 < p < 1$ is not locally convex (seminorms definition)

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I am reading Conways A Course in Functional Analysis.

A locally convex space is a topological vector space whose topology is defined by a family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}$ such that $\bigcap_{p \in P} \{x:p(x)=0 \}=(0)$.

I was looking for an example of a topological vector space that is not a locally convex space.

I found the following: [Why isn't $\ell^p$ locally convex for $0<p<1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867484/why-isnt-ellp-locally-convex-for-0p1)

Where it is stated that $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is not a locally convex space.

My Problem is that I do not understand the proof/answer. As far as I understand, I need to show that the topology (induced by the metric) can't come from a family of seminorms. (But I also do not know how to approach this.)
Is there another way, to show that the space is not locally convex without using this definition?

Some help would be appreciated.

One helpful thing,was [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581514/equivalent-definitions-of-locally-convex-topological-vector-space), which was kindly link by a user in the comments.

Comment: The problem is that your definition is not the standard one. If you prove equivalence of two definitions, you will see that the post answers your question. Normally you define a space to be locally convex when if $U$ is a open neighborhood of $0$, then there exists $V$, a convex neighborhood of $0$, such that $V\subseteq U$.

Comment: And indeed, if $U$ is open and $0\in U$, there must exist $p_1, ..., p_n$ and $r_i$ such that $V = \{x\in X : p_1(x) < r_1, ..., p_n(x) < r_n\}\subseteq U$. Now $V$ must be convex (why?).

Comment: @Jakobian If $U$ is open and $0 \in U$, why must there exist $p_1,..,p_n$ and $r_i$ such that .... . (I am sorry if it's  obvious, and I don't see it, I just started the topic topological vector spaces/locally convex topological vector spaces a few days ago)

Comment: Can you unravel what it means to be generated by a family of seminorms?

Comment: @Jakobian As far as I understand, given a vector space $X$ and a family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}$ the topology on $X$ induced by $\mathcal{P}$ has a subbasis at $x_0 \in X$, $B_p(x_0,\epsilon)=\{x \in X: p(x-x_0)< \epsilon\}$, for $\epsilon >0$ and $p \in \mathcal{P}$.

Okey, so if a set $U$ is open for all $x_0 \in U$, $\exists p_1,...,p_n \in \mathcal{P}$, $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n>0$ such that $\cap_{k=1}^n B_{p_k}(x_o,\epsilon_k) \subseteq U$

Comment: Then since each of the $B_{p_k}$ is convex, $\cap B_{p_k}$ is also convex, right?

Comment: Since $0\in B_{p_k}(x_k, \varepsilon_k)$ you can assume that $x_k = 0$ for all $k$. This is from properties of the (semi)norm. But yes, I suppose you don't *need* to change the center. And yes you're correct in your second comment, this makes the intersection convex.

Comment: I guess the main issue is not the proof itself, while the equivalence of the two definition of locally convex t.v.s., in that case I think this post can help you [Equivalent definitions of locally convex topological vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581514/equivalent-definitions-of-locally-convex-topological-vector-space)

Comment: So, if it would be locally convex, the unit ball $B_1(0) $would contain a convex neighborhood $U$ of $0$, since the unit ball is open. Thus, there must exist a $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subseteq U$ (In the post I linked in my question, it is $B_{2 \delta})$. Is there something I am missing, or does the user who posted the answer just uses $B_{\text{diameter}}$(0) instead of $B_{\text{radius}}$?)

Comment: Note the comment by Marco. Here we just need the easy direction of the equivalence, which we already discussed.

Comment: @Jakobian Yeah, I think I did understand that part by now.

Comment: I'm voting to close it as a duplicate of [Why isn't $\ell^p$ locally convex for $0 < p < 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867484/why-isnt-ellp-locally-convex-for-0p1) since this and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581514/equivalent-definitions-of-locally-convex-topological-vector-space) question provide an answer to this question.

Comment: @Jakobian Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: The only thing that I am missing is the $||\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \delta^{1/p}e_i||_p^p=\delta n^{1-p}$. I only get $|\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \delta ^{1/p} e_i|^p=\delta n^{-\frac{p}{2}}$.

Comment: @Philip $\|\sum_{i=1}^n e_i\|_p^p = \sum_{i=1}^n 1^p = n$